# "Use Start full screen" option obtaining for Windows 10

Tags: windows, winapi

Is there a way to find "Use Start full screen" option?
Haven't found any suitable functions in Win10 SDK.

Also, tried to watch with Process Monitor to find out setting location, but only database log changes
{local app data for user}\TileDataLayer\Database\EDB.log
which is locked for reading

Comment: First: Read this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/09/03/54760.aspx) from Raymond Chen.   Second: If the goal is not to arbitrarily overwrite the user's settings, you probably want to shed some light on exactly what you're trying to accomplish by changing this setting. Otherwise we can't hope to suggest alternatives.

Comment: The goal is just to read the setting without change